# How to get more details about issues in Crashlytics

Tags: google-fabric

I am using Crashlytics for Unity and everything seems to work, but the issues that are getting reported are pretty 'light'.

For example:
[image]

How can I get a stack trace for this exception? Do I have to enable some features? This happens for the iOS application.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you seeing this all on Unity exceptions? It seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: I think it has something to do with bitcode. I disabled bitcode and now some of the exceptions have more details. I will continue to investigate.